# Magento theme not get loaded

Tags: theme, skin

I have set up live code of one of my company's magento website at local side. I done all changes in `core_config_data` , then cleared cache and session folders still theme is not get loaded.

When I view source the page I found that css folder is missing from `skin/base/default` (may be done implicitly by developer) and when I copy css folder(containing styles.css, widget.css etc) theme get loaded but Magento default theme and not my custom theme.

Even I cannot make any changes at admin side as data not get saved on clicking on any button.

Please help in this issue.

Comment: You need to mention in admin panel that the theme has been changed from `default` to your `custom` theme. For this you must have access to Admin panel.

Comment: Unfortunately admin theme is also not get applied and saving any change at admin is also not working as button click is also not working at admin side. I checked that and theme selected in admin is correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I would not often suggest making changes via the database but in the case where you cannot access the admin section the package information is stored in the table `core_config_data` where the `path = 'design/package/name'`

I would suggest that you change your admin package and theme back to the default and see if that helps you to edit items from the admin section before you start to play around with the database.

Also make a backup before working directly with the database.